# Can one class in android studio handle several different in layout and purpose XML layouts

Tags: java, android-studio

Currently when I make a new layout I create a new class that handles that layout and then make a method to communicate with a class that the layout might communicate with, but can I use one class for everything. Like if I make a game can 1 class handle the Main Menu layout from which by pressing buttons you will be able to go to Options, High Scores and New Game. Can I do everything on a class ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a normal class that handles the layout. In Android, a class when extends an Activity or Fragment, it becomes one of the component of Android.

An Activity can render multiple layouts using `setContentView()` method. You can call this method with different layout as you click on different buttons.

**BUT**, this is a bad approach. To keep the same activity and change layouts, use **Fragments**. Fragments are part of an Activity that can have their own life cycle and can be attached or detached from Activity dynamically. They are mostly used for layouts for multiple sized devices. Read more about fragments [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).
Here is tutorial of how to use Fragment in Android: https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial